# Take from IObservable until collection reached count or time elapsed

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to fill a collection until any of these two conditions is satisfied:

- either allowed time of 5 seconds has completed, or
- collection reached the count of 5 items.

If any of these conditions is fulfilled, the method that i subscribed to should be executed (in this case Console.WriteLine)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sourceCollection = Source().ToObservable();
        var bufferedCollection = sourceCollection.Buffer(
            () => Observable.Amb(
                    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)//,
                    //Observable.TakeWhile(bufferedCollection, a=> a.Count < 5)
                ))
            );

            bufferedCollection.Subscribe(col => 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("count of items is now {0}", col.Count);
                });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Source()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var lst = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5 };
        while(true)
        {
            yield return lst[random.Next(lst.Count)];
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(0, 1500));
        }
    }
```

i managed to make it work with the Observable.Timer, but the TakeWhile doesnt work, how do I check for the collection count, does TakeWhile work for this or is there some other method? Im sure its something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the answer was in the documentation of Buffer - there's an overload that takes a parameter that specifies the maximum count. So I don't need `Observable.Amb`, I can just say

```
       var sourceCollection = Source().ToObservable();

        var maxBufferCount = 5;
        var bufferedCollection = sourceCollection.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), maxBufferCount, Scheduler.Default);

        bufferedCollection.Subscribe(col => 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("count of items is now {0}", col.Count);
                });

        Console.ReadLine();
```